# Greek word for battery

Tags: vocabulary, greek

What might a Greek have called a modern *battery*?  I think a good Latin word
would be *accumulator* (cf. German), but don't know how well something
corresponding would work in Greek (or what it would be).  *Battery* seems to be
some sort of military metaphor, which it would perhaps be too recherché to
translate to Greek.

Please say why the coinage would be plausible in the ancient language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greeks still exist, and they say *bataria* (spelled μπαταρία) for an electric battery.

On a more technical/formal registry, the word for *accumulator* is συσσωρευτής, and another word for *battery* is συστοιχία. Both words are derivations from roots present in New Testament Greek and would have been easily parsed by any “ancient” Greek, just like an ancient Roman would have recognized the word *accumulator* without having the faintest clue about what is meant.

While συσσωρευτής is the exact etymological equivalent of *accumulator,* συστοιχία and *battery* have somewhat different origins. *Battery* comes from the old French word *batterie,* meaning “a set of metal implements meant to be put together to be used” (from artillery to kitchenware: my  sources explain the relation with the verb *battre,* ”to beat”, in different ways and that discussion is off-topic here). Συστοιχία comes from the verb συστοιχέω, “to be tied together one after another”, just as power cells in a battery are: most probably, it was first used of batteries by someone who knew the French etymology.

Comment: συστοιχία sounds good.  I suspect the etymology is similar to that of 'battery'.

Comment: @Toothrot Edited the answer with some etymological notes.

Comment: Doesn't it seem that συστοιχία was first used of batteries with the etymology of _battery_ in mind?

Comment: @Toothrot Yes, it definitely seems so. I’ve added a final remark to my answer.

Comment: συστοιχια is ancient